# How to write List<double> to Json in scientific notation in c#?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, jsonconvert, jsonconverter

I'm trying to serialize List to json file like this

```
class ScientificDoubleConverter : JsonConverter
{
  public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    if (value is List<double> myList)
    {

      JArray myArray = new JArray();
      myList.ForEach(dblValue => myArray.Add(dblValue.ToString("E")));
      myArray.WriteTo(writer);

    }
  }
}
```

This works, but i get values with qoutes

```
"values": ["-9,811880E-002", "2,236657E-002", "-4,020144E-001", ...
```

I would like **no quotes and a point in value scientific notation**

```
"values": [-9.811880E-002, 2.236657E-002, -4.020144E-001, ...
```

Comment: Why do you care what format the JSON uses? It will be converted back to doubles when you deserialise it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson data export for MathLab

Comment: If MathLab  reads JSON, then it won't care either? I really don't understand why it must be formatted this way...

Comment: is there chance you could convert to scientific notation in javascript or you need it as in json?

Comment: mathlab does not require data in scientific notation. you'll get scientific notation by default for any numbers which are too large to display fully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're explicitly formatting the values. Don't do that - add the elements directly to the array:

```
if (value is List<double> myList)
{
    JArray myArray = new JArray();
    foreach (var element in myList)
    {
        myArray.Add(element);
    }
    myArray.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Or write directly to the writer:

```
if (value is List<double> myList)
{
    writer.WriteStartArray();
    foreach (var element in myList)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(element);
    }
    writer.WriteEndArray();
}
```

This may not get to the exact representation you want (in terms of scientific notation), but it *will* get to a valid JSON representation of the data you're trying to serialize. Anything reading the JSON should be able to read the exact same value from the JSON.

If you absolutely *have* to customize the format, you can use `JsonWriter.WriteRawValue`, using the invariant culture to format your values. But I'd *strongly* advise you not to. I'd be really surprised at a JSON parser that can't handle the regular output of Json.NET. Here's a complete example if you really, really have to do it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var writer = new JsonTextWriter(Console.Out);
        var list = new List<double>
        {
            -9.811880E-002,
            2.236657E-002,
            -4.020144E-001
        };
        WriteList(writer, list);
    }

    static void WriteList(JsonWriter writer, List<double> list)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            writer.WriteRawValue(element.ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[-9.811880E-002,2.236657E-002,-4.020144E-001]
```

Comment: this wil not give me the scientific notation

Comment: @Juri: No, but it will give you valid JSON which can be read by any JSON parser to give the right result. What is your reason for needing scientific notation?

Comment: @Juri: I'll see whether I can write some code to do that, but I would *strongly* suggest that you don't use it. The more "customized" your serialization is, the more likely it is you'll end up with a bug in it.

Comment: data export for MathLab

Comment: @Juri: Are you saying MathLab can't parse the standard JSON created by Json.NET? That would seem highly odd.

Comment: @Juri: I've added a way of serializing to scientific notation, but as I say, I'd be really surprised if you actually needed it.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `dblValue.ToString("E")` which is why you're getting strings.

Comment: yes, this is the reason - but what is the solution?

Comment: What happens if you remove it?

Comment: i will get a double (with no quote) but not in scientific notation :-/

Comment: @Juri I'm not sure how you would expect this to be solved. Scientific notation is a domain concept, not a datatype. If you want SN then it's a string. If you want just the value, then it's a double. Where lies the problem with a string or an actual double?

Answer (score 0):

*JArray.Add* except Object too as argument. So, you don't have to convert your double to string. Just directly add to array.

Have a look [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) for details.

Comment: this wil not give me the scientific notation